# EF fill a list using a Select Stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a DB first project approach in my project. Tables are created in the DB and their is no DBset reference to them in the code. All operations are via a stored procedure. I need to create a C# function that returns a list of records from DB using a SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GET`(
in startDate DATETIME,
in endDate DATETIME)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM DB.Table;
END
```

In my C# code

```
    public List<object> GetAuditTrails (DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
    {
        List<MySqlParameter> paramList = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("StartDate", StartDate.HasValue ? StartDate.Value : null));
        paramList.Add(new MySqlParameter("EndDate", EndDate.HasValue ? EndDate.Value : null));

        var auditTrails = this.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"CALL GET(@StartDate, @EndDate)", paramList);

        return new List<object>();
    }
```

but the param auditTrails is an int and not a list. How can I get a list of objects from calling the SP?

Comment: ?? The SP parameters are not used in your SP code.

Comment: @Akina what do you mean?

Comment: `ExecuteSqlRaw` executes the given SQL against the database and returns **the number of rows affected** and not the output rowset.

Comment: I mean that either your SP is wrong or you provide a pattern of it (you'd tell about this in such case).

Comment: Change `ExecuteRawSql` to `SqlQuery<object>`. Also you should return `auditTrails`, not new list.

Comment: @Roman it is saying that SqlQuery<object> is not available in Database

Comment: Maybe you need in something similar to `FromSqlRaw().ToList()`?

Comment: same issue. not available

Comment: Which version of EF do you use?

Comment: latest version available